# Distance between points in metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Just started on metric spaces, and when i am doing a **particular** question, i realized that for any two points in the metric space set, say $x,y \in X$. We have $d(x+y,y) = d(x,0)$.

Now this gets me to wonder if it is true for all cases. If i take the lament meaning of $d(x,y)$ to be the distance between $x$ and $y$. then the distance between $x+y$ and $y$ and the distance between $x$ and $0$ is indeed the same for all case. However , since i am new, i do not if there is any counter example to this, or am i understanding it too shallow.

Comment: What is $"+"$ in a metric space ?? What is $"0"$ in a metric space ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you write "$+$" and "$0$", I guess that you are considering a metric on a vector space.

If we are in a *normed vector space*, where $$d(x, \, y) := ||x-y||,$$ then the answer to your question is affirmative, because $$d(x+y, \, y ) = ||x+y-y|| = ||x|| = d(x, \, 0).$$

For an *arbitrary* norm on a vector space, the result is in general false. For instance, consider the Post Office metric on a normed space $X$, given by $$d(x, \, y):= \begin{cases} 0 & \textrm{ if } x=y \\ ||x|| + ||y|| & \textrm{ if } x \neq y. \end{cases}$$
Then if $x \neq 0$ we have $$d(x+y, \, y) = ||x+y||+||y||,$$ which is in general different from $d(x,\, 0)= ||x||$.